# Sending mail through Google Apps / Gmail. Dont store in 'sent'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, google-apps

I am using a 'noreply@domain.com' alias on my 'personal@domain.com' Google Apps / Gmail account to send emails over SMTP from my Rails 3.2 application.

I made sure that all replies to this address are automatically trashed (many undeliverables, spam, fake addresses, etc)

Sadly, all mails sent are being stored in the 'sent items' folder on my 'personal@domain.com' account. This includes PDF attachments and password resets.

Is there a way to make sure that mails sent from my Rails app are not stored in the my personal sent folder?

Comment: Do you want them to be stored somewhere else or do you want them to be deleted?

Comment: Deleted. Preferably when sending through the SMTP of Gmail with my Rails app I only want to use Google's service as a simple relay.

Comment: Not sure if you can do that. Maybe you could create a filter so that message send by noreply@ are moved to Trash?

Comment: Why don't you simply use two separate accounts?